# Show that the size of the pre-image $(\psi(x))$ is the same for all $x$. What is this size equal to?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Let $\psi: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism, and let $K=\operatorname{ker}(\psi)$. Define the canonical homomorphism $\varphi: G \rightarrow G/K$ by $\varphi(x) = xK$.

Show that the size of the pre-image $(\psi(x))$ is the same for all $x$. What is this size equal to? .

My thoughts:
First I showed that $\varphi^{-1}(x) =xK$ . and i know that logically this would be the size of the pre image of $\psi$ but I dont know how to show it.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to show *sets* have the same cardinality? The answer from David gives a mapping of sets which is a bijection betwen the kernel and any coset $xK$ which means $|K| = |xK|$. I.e that the cardinality of any coset equals the cardinality of the kernel. You've already justified that $\varphi^{-1}(x) = xK$, so you just need to put those two pieces together.

Comment: @IrvingRabin But I don't see how all of this relates to  $ψ^{−1}$ . how is the kernel or any coset $xK$ related to the pre image of $ψ$.

Comment: @user20194358 as i wrote below, you use the fact that cosets are equal sized. Now, you only have to show that the preimage of $\psi(x)$ is the coset $xK$

Comment: @simo210 yes i understand your proof but by doing your proof then I wouldnt need to show a bijection. since i already know all cosets are equal size and the pre image is equal to a coset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $\psi^{-1}(\psi(x))=xK$ for any $x \in G$, where $K=ker(\psi)$

Let $x\cdot k \in xK$, then $\psi(x\cdot k)=\psi(x)$ because $k\in K=ker(\psi)$, thus $xK\subseteq \psi^{-1}(\psi(x))$.

Now, let $g \in \psi^{-1}(\psi(x))$, then $\psi(g)=\psi(x)$ and $\psi(x \cdot g^{-1})=1_H$, meaning $x \cdot g^{-1}=k$ for some $k \in K$.
Thus $g=x \cdot k^{-1} \in xK$, meaning $xK \subseteq \psi^{-1}(\psi(x))$

Now, from Lagrange's Theorem on subgroups, we know that all cosets of a subgroup are equal sized. In this case, we get $xK=x'K$ for any $x,x' \in G$. But we showed that $\psi^{-1}(\psi(x))=xK$ for any $x \in G$, then all pre-images of $\psi(x)$ all equal sized.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $G$ is finite, or at least that $K$ is finite index? Anyway, in that case you're almost there--you need only show that the map [of sets] $K\to xK$ defined by $k\mapsto xk$ is a bijection. It's obviously surjective by definition of the coset $xK$, and if $xk=xk'$ we can left-multiply by $x^{-1}$ to yield $k=k'$. Now of course $|xK|=|x'K|$ for any $x,x'\in G$ since we just showed each of those cosets is the same size as $|K|$.

Comment: I dont understand how this does anything with the pre image. i dont understand the proof tbh